# "for a field" vs. "to a field"

Tags: prepositions

I'm a software engineer. One of my friends, Daniel is an ophthalmology surgeon. For me, ophthalmology is more professional while eye is more common and easier to understand.

Is it clear and natural to say it like this?

> I'm a layman **for/to** ophthalmology field, in contrast, Daniel is profession (technical guy) in that field.

Comment: More commonly, perhaps, *I'm a layman **in the** ophthalmology field*.

Comment: It sounds like I'm going to work in the ophthalmology field, as a software engineer, right?

Comment: No - saying you're a "layman" in / on / to / for / etc. [some field / discipline / subject] doesn't particularly imply that you ***are going to*** work in that area in the future. It just means you're not ***professionally*** knowledgeable about it (*at time of speaking*, but usually with the implication that this isn't going to change; it's an "enduring" characteristic, like being male, or fair-skinned).

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

> When it comes to ophthalmology, I am a layman. In contrast, Daniel is a professional in that field.

Other choices:

> In regards to the field of ophthalmology... I am a layman.

> I am a layman, when it comes to ophthalmology.

I do not think these are correct:

> I'm a layman **to** the field of ophthalmology *

> I'm a layman **for** the field of ophthalmology *

The following is a bit closer to being correct. But I personally still wouldn't recommend it:

> I'm a layman **in** the field of ophthalmology *

Because this seems to indicate you are "in" the field. In the cases where you aren't in the field *at all*, then the preposition "in" shouldn't be used.

Comment: I agree that I would never use "a layman for the field". "To", however, could be a possible option. I wouldn't use layman with it though. I would say "a newcomer/latecomer _to_ that field". As you've correctly pointed out saying "layman" suggests the person could be an outsider and thus is not actually _in_ the field. I think the same logic applies to "to a field": a layperson hasn't exactly come to the field.